# Getting Error with SSL Certificate in swift

Tags: ios, iphone, swift3

```
ERROR:(You can't able to connect server without SSL certificate)
```

I have to use fullchain.pem file. How can I use that fullchain.pem file in my project to access the server and retrive the secure information from the server(fullchain.pem file was given by my backend team)

Please help me...
Advanced Thanks

Comment: You need to use fullchain.pem to retrieve infomation from the server? In which programming language you are working at to accomplish your task?

Comment: i'm using swift